# What is HTTP cache best practices for high-traffic static site?

Tags: iis, web, http-caching

We have a fairly high-traffic static site (i.e. no server code), with lots of images, scripts, css, hosted by IIS 7.0

We'd like to turn on some caching to reduce server load, and are considered setting the expiry of web content to be some time in the future. In IIS, we can do this on a global level via "Expire web content" section of the common http headers in the IIS response header module. Perhaps setting content to expire 7 days after serving.

All this actually does is sets the `max-age` HTTP response header, so far as I can tell, which makes sense, I guess.

Now, the confusion:

1. Firstly, all browsers I've checked (IE9, Chrome, FF4) seem to ignore this and still make conditional requests to the server to see if content has changed. So, I'm not entirely sure what the max-age response header will actually effect?! Could it be older browsers? Or web-caches?
2. It is possible that we may want to change an image in the site at short notice... I'm guessing that if the max-age *is* actually used by something that, by its very nature, it won't then check if this image has changed for 7 days... so that's not what we want either

I wonder if a best practice is to partition one's site into folders of content really won't change often and only turn on some long-term expiry for these folders? Perhaps to vary the querystring to force a refresh of content in these folders if needed (e.g. /assets/images/background.png?version=2) ?

Anyway, having looked through the (rather dry!) [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html), and some of the [tutorials](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/), I still don't really have a feel for what's right in our situation.

Any real-world experience of a situation similar to ours would be most appreciated!

Comment: high-traffic with no server code + IIS 7.0 sounds like the best possible optimization would be to use nginx instead (the only valid excuse in my opinion to use something as inferior as IIS is if you really need it for server-side code that's not supported on another webserver -- since that's not the case, there is no reason really).

Comment: Really don't want a webserver-bashing competition here - cannot change platform for a huge variety of reasons that I really don't want to go into... just interesting HTTP best practices.

Comment: I don't know if there is an option to add arbitrary headers in IIS, but what you want is `Expires:` and `Last Modified:`. That tells proxies and clients when to fetch a new copy. You can also soft-embed `Expires:` in HTML as `http-equiv="expires"` on images etc. Sorry if my comment on IIS sounded a bit harsh. It's just that it isn't precisely lightweight, and running an ultra-heavyweight program when it's not urgently necessary seems like the first thing to change in my opinion. But well, let's skip that. See if you can get those headers set, it will probably help :-)

Comment: Thanks. `max-age` is used instead of `expires` when specifying "x days".. but if I specify an explicit expiry date, then it uses `expires`. Both seem to be ignored by browsers. Also, `last modified` is always sent, and, yes, you can change any http header you want. I find IIS7 to be exceptionally good, but that also is another story :)

Comment: Funny, the expires header works just fine for me (with Firefox at least). The "may want to change images shortly" that you describe above is something that the ETag tries to work around, btw. But of course it means you will inevitably see proxies probing for it. I prefer just giving short-lived things a time to live of 3-4 days, this reduces requests by 90% already. Is using Coral cdn for your images an option?

Comment: Thanks for info - will look into ETag. I think possibly if the HTML page is not cached, then using a varying querystring will be one way to control the prompt refreshing of cached resources.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers fetch the HTML first, then all the resources inside (css, javascript, images, etc).

If you make the HTML expire soon (e.g. 1 hour or 1 day) and then make the other resources expire after 1 year, you can have the best of both worlds.

When you need to update an image, or other resource, you just change the name of that file, and update the HTML to match.

The next time the user gets fresh HTML, the browser will see a new URL for that image, and get it fresh, while grabbing all the other resources from a cache.

Also, at the time of this writing (December 2015), Firefox limits the maximum number of concurrent connections to a server to six (6).  This means if you have 30 or more resources that are all hosted on the same website, only 6 are being downloaded at any time until the page is loaded.  You can speed this up a bit by using a content delivery network (CDN) so that everything downloads at once.